# How to append only one item at a time to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add one element to an array that gets appended to an HTML div one at a time each time a user clicks a button. However, each time I try, multiple instances of the element gets added to the array and it displays way more than what I want. How do I only add one at a time?

```
var testArray = [];
var toBeAdded =
  '<div class="grid-x">' +
  '<div class="cell medium-2">' +
  "<p>Date</p>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-7">' +
  "<h4>Title</h4>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-3">' +
  "<h5>Delete</h5>" +
  "</div>" +
  "</div>";

$(".add-new-info").click(function() {
  testArray.push(toBeAdded);
  $(".info-container").append(testArray);
});
```

html

```
<div class="add-new-info">Click to add</div>
<div class="info-container"></div>
```

Comment: You're adding to the array, then appending the entire array. Use `$(".info-container").html(testArray);` instead of `append()`

Comment: Or skip the array and just append the html string each time

Comment: `$(".info-container").append(toBeAdded);`

Comment: Do you have other elements to add ? If no, why using an `array` when you can just use `.append(toBeAdded)` instead of `.append(testArray)`.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have commented, you are adding to the array and then appending.

You can try

```js
var testArray = [];
var toBeAdded =
  '<div class="grid-x">' +
  '<div class="cell medium-2">' +
  "<p>Date</p>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-7">' +
  "<h4>Title</h4>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-3">' +
  "<h5>Delete</h5>" +
  "</div>" +
  "</div>";

$(".add-new-info").click(function() {
  testArray.push(toBeAdded);
  $(".info-container").append(toBeAdded);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-new-info">Click to add</div>
<div class="info-container"></div>
```

Or this:

```js
var testArray = [];
var toBeAdded =
  '<div class="grid-x">' +
  '<div class="cell medium-2">' +
  "<p>Date</p>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-7">' +
  "<h4>Title</h4>" +
  "</div>" +
  '<div class="cell medium-3">' +
  "<h5>Delete</h5>" +
  "</div>" +
  "</div>";

$(".add-new-info").click(function() {
  testArray.push(toBeAdded);
  $(".info-container").html(testArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-new-info">Click to add</div>
<div class="info-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var testArray = [];
let toBeAdded =
  `<div class="grid-x">
      <div class="cell medium-2">
          <p>Date</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cell medium-7">
          <h4>Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="cell medium-3">
          <h5>Delete</h5>
      </div>
   </div>`;

$(".add-new-info").click(function() {
  testArray.push(toBeAdded);
  $(".info-container").append(toBeAdded);
});

<div class="add-new-info">Click to add</div>
<div class="info-container"></div>
```